# responsive Masonry layout component not resizing according to the viewport

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

Here is the demo. https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-swartz-tuo1t

I use this react Masonry layout component to achieve the Masonry grid to store my images. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-masonry

According to the doc, we can specify `columnsCountBreakPoints` to make the component contain different number of columns according to the breakpoint where "Keys are breakpoints in px, values are the columns number"

However in my demo, where I set `columnsCountBreakPoints` to be { 350: 1, 750: 2, 900: 3 }, it always only shows one column, which should have been the case when viewport width is 350px.

I spent a lot of time debugging but couldn't seem to find the reason. I suspect it was because somehow the css I wrote make my viewport width always be below 350px but I am not sure. I really hope someone can point out the problem here for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the css with @media screen

```
.masonry {
    @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .grid-sizer { width: 33%; }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    .grid-sizer { width: 50%; }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 350px) {
    .grid-sizer { width: 100%; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. although I am not really good at css, I am aware that I can use @media screen to do responsive design. However I don't think the issue here is that I didn't use `@media screen` to set the break point myself. The component exposes the props for us to set that up without us needing to write media query. as I said there might be something weird happened to the side of my viewport, but I can't figure out why.